# Create a Diagonal Custom UIView in Swift

Tags: uiview, swift3

I am working on designing custom UIimageview in swift. I want to create a UIimageview using beizerpath  similar to this [image]

The coding should be in swift.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Create a `CAShapeLayer` and supply it a `path` and a `fillColor`:

```
@IBDesignable
public class AngleView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var fillColor: UIColor = .blue { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    var points: [CGPoint] = [
        .zero,
        CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0),
        CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1),
        CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    ] { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    private lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let _shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.layer.insertSublayer(_shapeLayer, at: 0)
        return _shapeLayer
    }()

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor

        guard points.count > 2 else {
            shapeLayer.path = nil
            return
        }

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: convert(relativePoint: points[0]))
        for point in points.dropFirst() {
            path.addLine(to: convert(relativePoint: point))
        }
        path.close()

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }

    private func convert(relativePoint point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: point.x * bounds.width + bounds.origin.x, y: point.y * bounds.height + bounds.origin.y)
    }
}
```

Now, I made this [designable](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) (so if you put it in a separate framework target, you can add this view right in your storyboard and see it rendered there). It still works if you're not using storyboards. It just can be convenient to do so:

[image]

I also used relative coordinates (with values ranging from zero to one) and have a method to convert those to actual coordinates, but you can hard code your coordinates if you want. But using this as values from zero to one, you have an angular view that can participate in auto-layout without needing to worry about changing specific coordinate values.

Finally, minor things that might seem trivial, but I construct the `path` in `layoutSubviews`: That way, as the view changes size (whether via auto-layout or programmatic changes), the view will be correctly re-rendered. Likewise, by using `didSet` for `fillColor` and `points`, if you change either of those, the view will be re-rendered for you.

Feel free to change this as you see fit, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea of just having a `CAShapeLayer` with a custom `path`.

---

If you use `insertSublayer`, you can then combine this with other subviews of the AngleView, e.g.:

[image: this is a flower]

Comment: Thank you so much @Rob for your valuable answer.. I want to know one thing. why have you given 2 in condition:

 guard points.count > 2

Comment: We're defining a shape to "fill", so I need more than two points. E.g. if you have two points, you only have a one-dimensional line, and thus nothing to "fill". And obviously, if you have less than two points, you _definitely_ have nothing to fill.

Comment: Thanks @Rob understood. Well thank you for your answer..really helped me a lot. Actually I just started with core graphics..I also need a label to be placed in the right bottom corner & an image View to be placed at the top right corner.. So for that also I need to set the coordinates for both, bcoz its not in storyboard that we directly drop them from the objects library..

Comment: It worked but I was not able to add imageView, Label or button on it. All the three gets hidden under the CAShapeLayer..

Can this be achieved only by adding a subView rather than a .addSublayer( )

Comment: The code is same as above & it has also rendered in the storyboard. When I try to drag the UIImageView object & place it on the custom design pattern, my object gets placed below this custom design pattern. I tried to create a UIImageView instance but wasn't able to call this function:

insertSublayer:above:
insertSublayer:atIndex:
insertSublayer:below:

reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/BuildingaLayerHierarchy/BuildingaLayerHierarchy.html

http://darren102.github.io/uiviewhierarchy.html

Comment: @GauravKapur - Use `insertSublayer` (shown in revised answer above) and then you can marry this with other subviews of the `AngleView`...

Comment: @Rob. how can i add imageview i complete to that

Comment: Excellent answer! 1 question though... I noticed that the view's background color, exists independently of the `shapeLayer`'s and i can't change it! Any ideas?

Comment: @SotirisKaniras - Just set the `backgroundColor` of the view. E.g. https://imgur.com/Jecbf2v

Comment: I also tested changing it programmatically and it worked fine. Perhaps you can post your own question showing us a reproducible example of the problem, because it's working for me and we've gone beyond the scope of what we can reasonably resolve in comments here...

Answer (score 4):

I'm using something like this and it worked fine, you can add any thing you want to the view

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    // Get Height and Width
    let layerHeight = layer.frame.height
    let layerWidth = layer.frame.width
    // Create Path
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    //  Points
    let pointA = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let pointB = CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: 0)
    let pointC = CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: layerHeight)
    let pointD = CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight*2/3)
    // Draw the path
    bezierPath.move(to: pointA)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: pointB)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: pointC)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: pointD)
    bezierPath.close()
    // Mask to Path
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    layer.mask = shapeLayer
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `UIImageView` with SVG content for such purposes.

The `bounds`, `frame`, `layer` and such things just don't work for me for different screen sizes. If I set up the constraints correctly, image view just does what I want, and since I use a vector image (SVG), it will scale properly.

Use this snippet for a triangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100" height="100">
  <polygon points="0,100 100,100 100,0 0,100" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

Save it as an .svg file and pull it into your assets. Add an image view to your view with this image, and you're ready.